# NoClassDefFoundError on AppEngine with org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working with EMF on a non-plugin, AppEngine Maven project that has the ***org.eclipse.core.runtime*** AND ***org.eclipse.ocl.ecore*** dependencies. The project runs perfectly when on the local server (I am using JDK 7). However, when deployed to GAE, I get the following two errors, sometimes one, sometimes the other:

1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform
2. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl

Both classes are indeed present in the JARs in the target folder's lib directory (also unzipped and checked the JARs). Here's how the dependencies look in the POM:

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${version.core.runtime}</version>
</dependency>`

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.ocl</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.ocl.ecore</artifactId>
            <version>${version.oclecore}</version>
</dependency>`

Where could the problem lie? Am I missing something obvious? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes the GAE libraries and the client libraries you are using locally might not be the same. Try updating to the recent GAE client libraries and see if that resolves it

Comment: Hi @mhan, I am not using any client libraries.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

*Both classes are indeed present in the JARs in the target folder's lib
 directory (also unzipped and checked the JARs*

I can not see your application structure, but wherever these JARs are, if your application needs them to be the same in GAE as they are on your local machine; then you should make sure you are using the same version as present in the target version of GAE........ I used to have that problem because I started using GAE when it was new and client libraries used to change very fast.